# Rename multiple files removing last characters and renumbering

Tags: bash, rename, filenames

I have a photo directory with hundreds of files named in the format:

```
2013-08-02 19.21.27.jpg
```

I wish to keep the first 10 characters (date) and append "-001", etc. being consecutive for each date.

The output would be:

```
2013-08-02-001.jpg
2013-08-02-002.jpg
2013-08-03-001.jpg
```

etc.

I then plan to resize the jpg's using something like:

```
for file in *.jpg; do convert $file -resize 900x900\> 900x900-$file; done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it would probably be to use Perl's hashes:

```
perl -e '
    for (<*.jpg>){
        $date = substr($_,0,10);
        $counts{$date}++;
        rename $_ => "$date-".sprintf "%03d",$counts{$date}.".jpg";
    }
'
```

Careful, though, this code is untested. Try it on dummy files first.

Comment: Fantastic. This worked, but not without complaining: for (<*.jpg>){
> >         $date = substr($_,0,10);
> >         $counts{$date}++;
> >         rename $_ => "$date-".sprintf "%03d",$counts{$date};
> >     }
> '
syntax error at -e line 3, near ">"
syntax error at -e line 4, near "++;"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors. The file names changed as intended and I only had to add ".jpg" to get the finished product. What a time saver, Thanks very much.

Comment: @user52478 Right, I missed the `.jpg` part (adding to answer) but the file names shouldn't have changed if execution were indeed aborted. Strange... Are you sure you copied the code exactly as is?

Comment: After that initial complaint, I broke up your commands, entering them in three parts, a) perl -e ', b) for etc., and c) the final '. So the end result was the application of the code twice. This may explain the result.